# See other Twitter users’ timelines

Tags: twitter

Is the "See Other Users’ Timelines" feature still available in the "new Twitter"?

In the Mashable write up, ["Twitter Lets You See Other Users' Timelines"](http://mashable.com/2011/05/26/new-twitter-feature-user-timeline/), they show this Twitter feature where you can read the Tweets of someone else's following list as if you were using their account.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be available anymore. A "hack" would be to make a list with all/most of the friends of the "other user" and see what he/she sees without friending those people.

Answer (score 2):

This view no longer exists. It's just gone.

Alternatively, look up who the Twitter user is following and [add all those people to a list](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists). You can [add up to 500 per list](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169276-i-m-having-trouble-with-lists).

You don't have to follow each of these people on the list, but when you view it (which can be made public or private) you will see a timeline of Tweets by users on that list.

The only thing you will miss are explicit replies to anyone if they don't use the trick of putting a character before the at sign (`@`).

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to do this on the website; the feature was available briefly recently but disappeared again.

However, you can get exactly this functionality by using the desktop app TweetDeck (which is owned by Twitter).

Choose *Add Column*, then *Home*, then enter the username of the person whose timeline you want to see.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Can only add "home" for a user that you have authenticated as.

Answer (score -1):

[Read someone else's Twitter timeline: https://otherside.site](https://otherside.site/)

Create private list by default.

---

You can also try this free iOS 6.1+ app.

Mashable: 
[ShadowMe App Lets You Pretend You're Someone Else on Twitter](http://mashable.com/2012/10/31/shadowme/)

---

Dead service
[TwtRoulette - View your friend's home timeline](http://labs.stephenou.com/twtroulette)